# Questions on string.xml and size of the icon

Tags: android

In string.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">nameofmyapp</string>
</resources>
```

I wanna change the text size how do I do that..also I want to increase the size of my icon 
which appears on my phone.. I tried google's 
http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-notification.html#source.type=text&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0.2&source.text.text=Correct!&source.text.font=Helvetica&shape=square&name=example
Didn't work! any suggestions? 
 #newbie #thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the size of the name string and size of icon on the home screen, such that it will appear bigger relative to other apps, you can not do this.

The launcher that is installed on the user's device determines how to display the icon + title, you have no control over this.

Comment: Well it is appearing smaller than the other apps..so I figured you have a default

Answer (score 0):

Strings in string.xml only contain values.
How it should be displayed must be specified at the time it is used in UI context.
For example, if you use app_name in TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```